# Google maps as div background doesn't work in wordpress. Works in HTML

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I built a contacts page which includes a banner with google maps as the background. This was meant to be a basic website, but it has now turned into a wordpress blog.

This gmaps banner that works in my basic html site no longer displays anything in wordpress.

Chrome tools gives me this error message:

> http://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&action=apiboot2&rt=main.52
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I have tried turning off my ad blocker, as others have suggested, but that didn't work. I've also tried to use this plug-in: [Leaflet Maps Marker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker/)

but that outputs a shortcode and I don't know how to insert that into my header.

The script used:

```js
<!-- Include the Google Maps API library - required for embedding maps -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
// The latitude and longitude of your business / place
var position = [52.1656463, 8.6104517];
 
function showGoogleMaps() {
 
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]);
 
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16, // initialize zoom level - the max value is 21
        streetViewControl: false, // hide the yellow Street View pegman
        scaleControl: true, // allow users to zoom the Google Map
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: latLng
    };
 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
        mapOptions);
 
    // Show the default red marker at the location
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
}
 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', showGoogleMaps);
</script>
```

It affects this div:

```html
<!-- Banner -->
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner">
                <div id="googlemaps"></div>
              <div class="banner-title">
                <header>Kontakt</header>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and styled:

```css
#googlemaps { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: do you have a CSP on your wordpress site?

Comment: No, I don't. What effect might that have?

Answer (score 0):

First I would try changing the css and increasing the `z-index`. Test it with a large number like 1000

If that doesn't work, you mentioned using the Leaflet Plugin. You can add shortcodes to php files using the following

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[mapsmarker....]');
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to add shortcode to php files. It's a good temporary solution, but I'd rather get it working without relying on a wordpress plugin